# InDesign: numbered list, add banner in background of each number

Tags: adobe-indesign

I’m new to InDesign. I know how to make a numbered list in InDesign and also how to style the numbers (font, colors). But I want behind each number to be a banner I have made in Illustrator. I need something like the result in the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I don’t think there’s an automated way of doing that with a regular list, short of making a font where the numbers have the banner as their background. Even then, what happens when you get to 10? Bigger, stretched banner? Separate banners?

Comment: Maybe the banner is onesize that fits 2 digits and numbers are aligned in center so to look nice. I can’t imagine that a designer for a pdf including 800 exercises pastes the banner one by one with not having an automated solution!

Comment: In the screen shot you’ve shown, I’d wager the numbers are _not_ auto-incrementing numbers from a numbered list. They are more likely to be anchored objects. When I said ‘automated way’, what I really meant was that I don’t think this is doable as a dynamic numbered paragraph style. You can of course automate it, but in the sense that you can change regular paragraph numbers into these fancy anchored objects by running them through a script. If this is from an 800-page exercise file, it’s likely that’s what the original designer did.

Comment: I see. So can you describe how you would do it so to have this result?

Comment: I would probably start by seeing if I could make an object style that mimicks the desired form as closely as possible: pink background, dark pink drop shadow with no spread, paragraph style, anchored object position options set to fit with the right position, etc. Then with a script I’d iterate over the numbered paragraphs (by paragraph style), extract the paragraph number, create a polygon with the desired size and shape (this will probably take some testing), convert it to a text frame and insert it as an anchored object with the created object style and the extracted number as its contents.

Comment: thanks for your response! Only sure: i don't have the knowledge nor the experience to write a script! if you know automated scripts for this, please write it. Thanks again for your quck responses!

Comment: Part of it can be handled by the script given in [this answer on Adobe Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/how-to-get-full-paragraph-number-as-displayed-on-the-page-in-extendscript/m-p/12778734#M467245). That just inserts a regular, rectangular text frame, though. Building the polygon is probably the trickiest bit, but it is possible.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try it!